# How can I read/print a specific column using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

My code and input file are below. But my code doesn't print what I want. It prints all contents of the input file. But I want to print only "standard deviation" column. How can I do this using bash script?

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/path/input.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "$line" >> out.xvg
done <"$file"
```

input.txt:

```
The terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version
of the License.

Read 2 sets of 201 points, dt = 0.01


                       standard      
set      average       deviation    

a1   2.445857e+01   2.145235e+01   
a2  -1.158344e+02   5.452454e+01  
a3   2.314415e+04   3.652432e+05  
a4  -5.153647e-03   7.235728e-02
```

Requested output:

```
2.145235e+01   
5.452454e+01  
3.652432e+05  
7.235728e-02
```

**Updated:**

```
sed '/a1/,$!d' input.xvg | sed '$d' | awk '{print $3}' > output.txt
```

This code works but it ignores the last line of the file. I checked the input file. That is missing the newline character after its last line. But I want to print all lines of "standard deviation" column. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: if you can use awk `awk 'NR>10{print $3}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the cut argument you can solve your problem :

```
echo "$line" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 3
```

- `tr -s " "` removes all the `" "` (spaces) char to only one.
- `cut -d` defines your delimiter
- `-f` choses the colomn your want to print out (fieldset)

Comment: well isn't "trim" but "tr", my bad. I edit my response

Comment: It works now. But It doesn't print only "standard deviation" column. It also prints some characters like "sets, deviation.."

Comment: My solution will be to use this command on your input file `tail -n +9 input.txt > output.txt`, and make your while/done on the output.txt file

(9 is the first line which will be copy in ouput.txt)

Comment: @William The tail operation can also be done on the stdin of the while loop directly. `done < <(tail -n +9 "$file")`

Comment: It is solved: `sed '/a1/,$!d' input.xvg | sed '$d' | awk '{print $3}' > output.txt`